# FtpWebRequest: 550 file not found error

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows-services, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to read a txt file from a ftp server and I'm getting a "550 File not found." error even I'm %100 sure that the file is there.

Here are the variations for URI I've tried:

```
ftp://server/MySubFolder/MyFile.txt
ftp://server/%2fMySubFolder/MyFile.txt
ftp://server/MySubFolder/%2fMyFile.txt
ftp://server/%2fMySubFolder/%2fMyFile.txt
ftp://server/%2f/MySubFolder/MyFile.tx
ftp://server/MySubFolder/%2f/MyFile.txt
ftp://server/%2f/MySubFolder/%2f/MyFile.txt
```

They all return the same result page:

```
200 Type set to I.
200 PORT command successful.
550 The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(file);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

I also tried calling [SetMethodRequiresCWD](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299) before creating my `FtpWebRequest` objects but it didn't help either.

My application is a .NET 4.0 Client Profile Windows Service.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried the same URL in a browser and does it work there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem like this: The server the service is running on is a Hyper-X virtual machine. Somehow the VM acts like a proxy. I added `request.Proxy = null;` to my requests and both upload and download works now.

Answer (score 0):

This solition didn't solve my problem. If there is someone who has this problem, can also try to connect ftp server by adding user name in url as fallows;

ftp://username@domain.com/uploads/fileName.jpg